# sql command not working with auto_increment

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.2

I am trying to create this table using the shell of postresql

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    surname VARCHAR(255)
);
```

But it doesn't work i get something like this

> ERREUR:  erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « AUTO_INCREMENT »
>   LINE 2:  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,

Comment: See the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-default.html

Comment: try using bigint for id , also check for the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres does not support `auto_increment`. Use `serial` instead.

```
CREATE TABLE Customer 
(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY, 
    name VARCHAR(255), surname VARCHAR(255) 
);
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/df1b3/1)

Comment: ERREUR:  erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « SERIAL »
LINE 3:     id INT  NOT NULL SERIAL PRIMARY KEY ,